# BaseActivity and Fragments - fragment destroyed when baseActivity is destroyed

Tags: android, android-activity, parent, activity-lifecycle

I have 3 activities that extend to a `baseActivity`. I extended these activities to `baseActivity` because I have a `slidingUpPanel`(https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) and I want this panel across all 3 activities. Now,this panel has dynamic views which change at regular intervals of time. So, the problem is if I press the back button on any activity, instance of baseActivity is destroyed, hence the views in the sliding up panel don't update anymore. I found a workaround by overriding the onBackPress method and starting the previous activity with intent so in that way, the baseActivity is resumed and not destroyed. But this method slows down the switching of activities. Is there any other way to solve this? I can give you the codes if necessary.

Thank you!

Comment: Share some code

Comment: Also why don&#39;t you use 3 fragment and 1 host activity instead of 3 activity, it will be quite manageable and standard.